# Localization of assets no longer working since updating xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, xcasset

I recently updated my project to be compatible with the newest xcode (11.6 - beta), previously I was using xcode 11.2.

My app is available in 2 languages, English and Spanish. Since updating xcode all localized images for the Spanish language no longer work, instead the English assets/images are being displayed. All Spanish strings are pulling through correctly, so as far as I can tell this only involves images which previously were localized in my `assets.xcassets` file.

Below is how I have my assets set up:

[image]

Is there something else which needs to be done now to properly display localized assets in non-default languages?

Comment: Solved - sort of. The issue was present on older devices using iOS 12 - not an issue on iOS 13